# SFDX and MDAPI Deploy Issues

Tags: metadata-api, salesforcedx

I just started working with DX again. When deploying a DX project using the MDAPI to a production org, I get a lot of feature missing errors during the deploy. I have my set my default scratch org config to match my environment but I'm still having issues.

One regular example is the following:

```
Error  test_deploy/profiles/Admin.profile    Admin    Unknown user permission: EditPublicReports
```

Has anyone had any success with this? Has anyone here had a chance to play with the new org shapes feature that is in pilot? I assume that feature is in response to situations such as this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found out that `sdfx force:source:pull` does overwrite the profile XML file, but it loses field level security and some other permissions, my solution was to add those manually to the profile XML.

I would suggest you perform a `mdapi retrieve` and a `source pull` and compare the resulting XML files.

More information can be found at: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000nZCLQA2&title=sfdx-force-source-pull-loses-field-level-security

Answer (score 0):

If they are standard profiles like Admin, Standard or Customer support I typically do not include them during mdapi conversion .This can be done using the .forceignore file .

More details about .forceignore can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm)

A Sample .forceignore file would look like below

```
force-app/main/default/profiles/Custom%3A Marketing Profile.profile- 
  meta.xml

force-app/main/default/profiles/Custom%3A Sales Profile.profile-meta.xml

force-app/main/default/profiles/Custom%3A Support Profile.profile-meta.xml

force-app/main/default/layouts/Opportunity-Opportunity Layout.layout-meta.xml
```

**Org Shape and Templates In DX**

Currently in Pilot and if you are interested please reach though your AE .

Comment: Ignoring the standard profiles, particularly System Admin, is not an option for me. We don't make any changes in production so system admin profile needs to be moved from scratch orgs to production on a regular basis.

Comment: System admins will have all the permissions by default .

Comment: Agreed. But I get that error all the time. Here is another one from this morning. 

```Error  test_deploy_524/profiles/Admin.profile              Admin              Unknown user permission: EditReports```

Comment: There is not lot one can do for these errors than script something to remove these tags or make sure to have a script that goes and checks few things on the other org where you are deploying

Comment: Sandboxes are great choices as well than complete new scratch org now that DX supports non scratch orgs

Comment: Sandboxes are not great for CI (which is my primary use case) or ISV partners. Regardless, changes made in a scratch org that are pulled using DX should not throw errors during an MDAPI deploy. Switching to a sandbox or ignoring key SFDC components should not be considered a "solution".

Comment: Do not agree with the comment sandboxes are not great for CI ? why not ? Agree that changes should mirror for mdapi deploy though .